# PHP send array to another PHP file

Tags: php

This may be a stupid question but I'm lost here. I need to send array with some data in it to another PHP file using POST variable. This is my form:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
        <label name="html[]" hidden><?php echo $array; ?></label>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

And this is test.php

```
<?php
    $html = $_POST['html'];
    for($i = 1; $i<=9; $i++){
        echo $html[$i];
    }
?>
```

So this is what I tried, but it's not displaying anything. please help

Comment: label is not a field so yes it wont work, read about HTML form input field or simple use the most common way to pass variables between PHP pages, SESSIONS.

Comment: You need to use `<input name="html[]">`. labels are not form fields. They are LABELS for form fields.

Comment: You really need to read up on a number of things.  First, from an HTML standpoint you need to understand forms and the differences between labels and inputs.  From a PHP standpoint, you can't just echo an array out into HTML and have it magically reform back into an array when it is posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a number of input elements with the same name, each of which will have one array item as its value:

```
<?php foreach ($array as $item) : ?>
<input type="hidden" name="html[]" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($item); ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Important points to keep in mind:

1. `$item` must always be a scalar value (string, integer, etc). You cannot pass in arrays piecemeal with this technique.
2. Never forget that since you are injecting variables into HTML output you *must* escape and/or sanitize them properly. In this case this is done with `htmlspecialchars`, which must know about your output encoding to work correctly in general (look up its third parameter).

There is also an alternative approach that can be used to pass arrays piecemeal through serialization:

```
<input type="hidden" name="html" 
       value="<?= htmlspecialchars(serialize($array)); ?>" />
```

And you would then unserialize it on the receiving end:

```
$html = unserialize($_POST['html']);
```

I 'm mostly including this option for completeness, as in practice session variables are a much better way of passing complex state between requests.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used session and everything is working. Sorry for stupid question but it's quite late now and I have to finish my project by tomorrow. Thank you again for this answer and for mentioning session

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary to put the data of the array in a hidden field? You can store the array in $_SESSION and access it. Btw, I think you have a problem, labels can be submitted, in that case you must put the data into an input field with type="hidden".